# How to set String (HH:mm) to UTC time with current date and convert it to local time

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, datetime-format

I need to convert a string that is in (HH:mm) format which is supposed to be in UTC time to the local TimeZone. How to add the present date to the string and convert it local time.

I have tried using the calendar

```
String utcTimeString = "06:00";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
now.setTime(sdf.parse(utcTimeString));
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You are well advised to use the modern API for dates, times, time zones, offsets, calendars and more:**

**`java.time`**

Doing so, it is pretty easy to

1. parse the time you receive
2. get the current date and
3. combine them to a date-time representation **with a certain time zone**

See this little example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a time object from the String
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("06:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
    // print it once in an ISO format
    System.out.println(localTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_TIME));
    // receive the date of today
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    // then use the date and the time object to create a zone-aware datetime object
    ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.of(today, localTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    // print it
    System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
}
```

The output is

```
06:00:00
2019-11-04T06:00:00Z[UTC]
```

Which you can format as desired using different `DateTimeFormatter`s.

Comment: It is worth noting that you can't really use the `java.time` API, unless you're targeting Android API 26 or more, but there's a backport for Andorid, here's the link: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Answer (score 2):

Try like the following.

```
public String getDateTimeInUTC(String yourTime){ 
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat currentDate= new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy ");

    String currentDateTime = currentDate.format(cal.getTime())+yourTime; // here concate your time with current date.
    System.out.println("Current date with given time: "+currentDateTime);

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    Date date = null;
    try {
       date = df.parse(currentDateTime);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    String formattedDate = df.format(date);

    return formattedDate;
}
```

Call `getDateTimeInUTC` like below

```
String strTime = "12:10"; // your string time in HH:mm format
String finalDateTime = getDateTimeInUTC(strTime);
System.out.println("Final date-time in UTC: "+finalDateTime);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Current date with  given time: Nov 04, 2019 12:10
Final date-time in UTC: Nov 04, 2019 18:10
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can Check this Out :**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());

//change the format according to your need
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

//Here you say to java the initial timezone. This is the secret
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
//Will print in UTC
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));    

//Here you set to your timezone
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
//Will print on your default Timezone
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```